# Tfidf Vectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, tokenize, tfidfvectorizer

I had taken a dataset for prediction of sentiment from the text review, initially, I clean the data (removal of punctuations, removal of stopwords, Tokenization). When I try to give Tokenized data as input to TFIDF vectorizer I am getting 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'. Please help me to get over this mistake.
[image: This is my Clean Text]

[TFIDF Vectorizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyjvQ.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyjvQ.png)[[image: Attribute Error]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyjvQ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSsHu.png

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

The TF-IDF vectorize works with raw (i.e., not tokenized) text and does the tokenization on its own.

The [`fit_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform) method requires an iterable of strings. Applying the NLTK tokenizer turns the reviews strings into a list of string (list of tokens).

If you for some reason do not trust the internal tokenizer in scikit-learn, you can a custom tokenizer:

```py
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=nltk.word_tokenize)
```